# Texstudio: Adding "additional shortcut" to a command that doesn't have one by default (specifically indent)

Tags: texstudio, document-configuration

I have been migrating my (La)TeX writing from TexMaker to TexStudio to try out a more configurable program. So far I really like the additional control it gives me. There are a few shortcuts I use a *lot* in TexMaker however that I would like to reproduce in TexStudio.

I know I can go to the `Options -> Configure TexStudio -> Shortcuts` to change almost any shortcut I want, which is great! Moreover, for each command, there is a "default" "current" and "additional" shortcut heading. My problem is that, for any command that doesn't appear to already have a shortcut listed under a given heading, I can't add one in that heading. Specifically, under `Editor -> Basic Key Mapping -> Tab or Indent Section` the "Current shortcut" is `Tab` which I want, but I also want to be able to use the shortcut `Ctrl + Shift + >`.

As I understand how it's suppose to work, I should be able to double click on the blank space below the "Additional shortcut" header next to the `Tab or Indent Section` and it should let me change (add) a shortcut, like it does if I double click the "Current shortcut". Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to happen. Anyone know how to add an "additional shortcut"?

Sorry for the long amount of detail, but this is a recurrent problem I'm having with other shortcuts, so this is the most annoying specific example, but some explanation would be nice just so I can fix the *other* shortcut issues myself.

Thanks!

Comment: As to why you can't add it at the "additional shortcut" column, I also couldn't figure. But you can add an extra row (at the bottom, "add row"), select it to be "Tab or Indent selection" and then configure the "Current shortcut" to be "Ctrl + Shift + >".

Comment: Thanks gusbrs, this seems to have worked, although it's a bit clunky. It's a decent workaround for now, although I'd still love to find out how to do it the intended way (via "additional shortcuts").
Thanks again though, at least I can add the shortcuts in the meantime and continue my work without muscle memory working against me heh.

Comment: @David: Sorry no, I want a shortcut to indent the text in the editor itself. ie the "tab" key (which is the default) shortcut, but I'd like to add another shortcut for that same "tab" effect. In TexStudio there is an "additional shortcut" column to do exactly this, but it doesn't seem to actually function for me, so I was wondering how to get it to work. Adding a second "current shortcut" solves the problem, but feels like a hack given the existing "additional shortcut" column option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an extra shortcut for `Tab or indent selection` by adding an extra row of shortcut with `add row` at the bottom of the `Shortcut` tab. Having added an extra row, you can attribute `Tab or indent selection` to it, and then select the `Current shortcut` to be `Ctrl + Shift + >`.

As to why the `Additional shortcut` doesn't work there, I can really only conjecture. But notice that the `Additional shortcut` works for all of TeXstudio's *Menu items*, but not with the `Basic key mapping`. Conversely, you cannot `add row` for menu items. In practice, you have a limit of up to two key bindings for each menu item, but none such limit to "basic key mappings" for which you can always add an extra row, and thus another shortcut. So it does look like this behavior is less a "workaround" than it is how it is intended to be. (But, again, I'm guessing here).

Comment: This is a good observation. I'll leave this for 24 hours to see if anyone has a comment to either confirm this is how it is "intended" to work, or if this is a bug and there is another way to add it as the "additional shortcut". If, after 24 hours, this is still the best solution I'll mark it as answer (If I don't, feel free to remind me).
Thanks again gusbrs.